# Right Aligned Text With Normal Hyphenation Rules

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

I am using a right aligned minipage with right aligned content. What I want is its content to look like the normal aligned one in the first minipage. The only difference being the last word I have underlined to be right aligned like it is in the second minipage. What I ask is depicted in the image.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}

\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}

\lipsum[1]

\end{minipage}

\end{flushright}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{flushright}

\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}

\begin{flushright}

\lipsum[1]

\end{flushright}

\end{minipage}

\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see, if the `RaggedLeft` from package `ragged2e` is what you looking for: `{\RaggedLeft <your text>}`.

Comment: @Zarko I tried it, and although it is better the hyphenation is not perfect.

Comment: what is the perfect hyphenation?

Comment: @Zarko When you right normal text like in the first minipage I show in the image. Basically what I want is to be like that but the sentence of the last line to start from the right.

Comment: then you actually ask: *how to make last line in text rigged left* :-) similar question you can find here (on TeX.SE).

Comment: @Zarko Well I don't know if I intend to just chage only one line. When you write normally every new sentence begins from the left. I thought it can be easy to make exactly the same but with every new sentence to start from the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeset the text in a box, remove the last line and reinsert it after having removed the glue at its end, preceded by `\hfill`. The following `lastflushright` environment behaves like a `minipage` with bottom alignment. It's not difficult to get also top or center alignment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lastflushright}[1]
 {\leavevmode\vbox\bgroup\@tempdima=#1\relax
  \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox\bgroup\color@begingroup
    \hsize\@tempdima\textwidth\hsize\columnwidth\hsize
    \@parboxrestore
    \@minipagerestore\@setminipage}
 {\@minipagefalse\color@endgroup\egroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\global\setbox1=\lastbox}
  \box\@tempboxa
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip}
  \nointerlineskip
  \hbox to\@tempdima{\hfill\box\@tempboxa}%
  \egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lastflushright}{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{lastflushright}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I thought that it would be something simple. Thank you very much though.